# Laravel Cache Forget Remember Forever Cache Not Working?

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-cache

I am trying to store the last run time of a scheduled job in Laravel. However, the cache is not updating the date. I want the cache to be remembered until the function is called again.

```
public function setLastRun() {
   Cache::forget('last_automation_api_run');
   Cache::rememberForever('last_automation_api_run', function () {
          return now()->toDateTimeString();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use remember and forget method in different functions.

```
public function getLastRun() {
   return \Cache::rememberForever('last_automation_api_run', function () {
          return now()->toDateTimeString();
   });
}

public function forgetLastRun() {
   \Cache::forget('last_automation_api_run');
}
```

Every time you delete the cache before fetching cache values makes, logically incorrect.

And you have to `return` the values coming from `rememberForever` cache method.

Comment: I am deleting the last cache set to that value before creating a new cache set to that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a clustered cache then there's a chance the first change hasn't propagated through the cache when you make the 2nd one. If that is the case (or generally for what you're doing) you can try the following:

```
public function setLastRun() {
   Cache::put('last_automation_api_run', now()->toDateTimeString());
}
```

this should mindlessly overwrite the current value rather than deleting and readding it.